# Regex to match any character from particular string

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

Basically I'm trying to see if the characters of a name appear in the characters of a string in order.

I.e. `'Across the rivers', 'chris'` => `true` because:

[image]

`'A crew that boards the ship', 'chris'` => `false` because:

[image]

I have this:

```
function nameInStr(str, name){
    let stringArray = Array.from(str);
    let testName = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
        if (stringArray[i].match(/any character from name/)) {
            testName += stringArray[i];
        }
    }
    if (testName === name) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

console.log(nameInStr('Across the rivers', 'chris'));
```

But as you can see I don't know how to test for when a single character matches any character from `name`. Is there a simple way to do this with a regex?

**EDIT - TESTING NEW METHOD**

```js
function nameInStr(str, name){
    let nameregex = new RegExp(".*" + name.split("").join(".*") + ".*");
    return str.test(nameregex);
}

console.log(nameInStr('Across the rivers', 'chris'));
```

Comment: basically, you want to turn your searched text 'abc' into the regex `a.*b.*c` (though it's not the most efficient solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn the name into a single regular expression:

```
let nameregex = new RegExp(".*" + name.split("").join(".*") + ".*");
```

then you just have to test:

```
return nameregex.test(str);
```

It'd have to get a little fancier to avoid potential problems with regular expression metacharacters in the name.

Comment: Hmm I'm getting a `TypeError: str.test is not a function` when I try that....see edit above.

Comment: @Pac0 same result for `.isMatch()` - `TypeError: str.isMatch is not a function`

Comment: @HappyHands31 right sorry I got it backwards, hold on. ... fixed now

Comment: @HappyHands31 huhu, wrong language, sorry, I removed my comment above

Comment: I'd hoped to solve this [codewars challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/whats-in-a-name/train/javascript) with that logic if you're interested. Only passes 43 / 69 tests, for some reason.

Comment: @HappyHands31 note that last comment in the instructions: the test should be case-insensitive. Thus the `new RegExp()` call needs `"i"` as the second argument.

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution :

Change your search term to a regex with `.*` in between every character.

For instance, `"chris"` -> `"c.*h.*r.*i.*s"`

Answer (score 3):

Try

```js
let re = new RegExp([..."chris"].join`.*`);

console.log( re.test('Across the rivers') );
console.log( re.test('A crew that boards the ship') );
```